# how to Like a Facebook page from android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to like facebook page from android application..is this possible in android?if yes then how?
    Any clue to achieve this?? answer will be appreciated

Comment: See this blog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

Comment: Here is Demo app: https://github.com/PinkelStar/pinkelstar-android-demo

Comment: @Lokesh thanks a lot from bottom of heart as i got idea about what i exactly want..thanks again man:):)

Comment: If that post helpful to your requirement, then vote up  my answer. Then only, next time people will recognize correct answer..

Comment: @Lokesh actually i m newbie on sflow so dnt know how to vote up to your comment???

Comment: Left of my answer, top arrow is there.. just click on it..